# check if the user choose image or not in image View

Tags: java, android, imageview

i have an application that has form that user should fill it ,i want to put the button "Next" disable until the user fill the fields. i know how to check the text Edit but how can i check if the user fill the image or not (image view will let the user choose an image from native gallery)

What i want:
how can i check if the user fill the image or not?

```
     if(checkEditText2(CaseName) && checkEditText2(CaseAge) && CheckRButtons(RBMale, RBFemale) &&  CheckSpinner(CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM )) {
    Nextb.setEnabled(false);}
    else {Nextb.setEnabled(true);}

        }
```

this is How check Edit text :

```
     // For EditText     
 private boolean checkEditText2(EditText edit) {
        return edit.getText().length() == 0;
    }
```

Comment: can you describe your question little more, its hard to understand what you really asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be done this simple:

```
if (ImageView == null){
Nextb.setEnabled(false); 
or
Nextb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else{
Nextb.setEnabled(true); 
or
Nextb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

same when you use bitmap:

```
if (BitMap == null){

}else{

}
```

Comment: no i want to check if the user pick an image or not, i do not think it is like this!

Comment: If the imageview is empty, then the user hasn't pick an image yet?

Comment: yeah i know but how can i put it in the code?so when the image view empty,the next button will be disable

Answer (score 0):

To check if the image view contains an image or not, we need to check, if the image of the image-view holds an image or not. Like following

```
if(imageView.image == NULL){
NSLog("Image of the image-view has no image");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (mediaPath == null)
 {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Pick Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 } else {
 //  register_useraddress_detail();
 }
```